# Linear gradient above img tag css

Tags: javascript, html, css, linear-gradients

I have a card and images are fetched from BE. The image is a background image of a card. The text goes above this image. I need to add a gradient above the image and below text. Also when user hovers over the card, gradient color should change. How do I make the image to fill the entire card and show linear-gradient on an image?

```css
.card {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 25px;
  min-width: 245px;
  height: 293px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 12px 1px var(--box-shadow-color);
  margin-right: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 2;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.64, 0.57, 0.67, 1.53);
  transform: scale(1);
  transition-duration: 300ms;
}
```

```html
<ul class="carousel" data-target="carousel">
  <li class="card" data-target="card">
    <img class="background" src="../scr/images/image.png">
    <h2> Title
      <h2>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
// enter code here
```

```css
.card {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 25px;
  min-width: 245px;
  height: 293px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 12px 1px var(--box-shadow-color);
  margin-right: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 2;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.64, 0.57, 0.67, 1.53);
  transform: scale(1);
  transition-duration: 300ms;
  display:inline-block;
 
}
.pickgradient {
  display:inline-block;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.65)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,0))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 100%); /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 100%); /* W3C */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#a6000000', endColorstr='#00000000',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}

img{
  position:relative;
  z-index:-1;
  display:block;
  height:200px; width:auto;
}
```

```html
<ul class="carousel" data-target="carousel">
  <li class="card" data-target="card">
    <div class="pickgradient">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/5I0iHYf.jpg" />
</div>
    <h2> Title dfdf
      </h2>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', 'San Francisco', Calibri, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.c-graidient {
  background: #000;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, #000000 0%, #000000 25%, #1e539e 50%, #ff3083 75%, #7800a8 100%);
  /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, #000000 0%, #000000 25%, #1e539e 50%, #ff3083 75%, #7800a8 100%);
  /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #000000 0%, #000000 25%, #1e539e 50%, #ff3083 75%, #7800a8 100%);
  /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  background-size: 400% 400%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: flex;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  max-width: 100vw;
  max-height: auto;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .5s all;
}
.c-graidient__img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background: #000;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: .5;
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
}
.c-graidient__title {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: .05em;
}
.c-graidient:hover {
  background-position: 100% 100%;
}
.c-graidient:hover__title {
  text-shadow: 0 0 20px black;
}
```

```html
<a class="c-graidient">
    <img class="c-graidient__img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1466657718950-8f9346c04f8f?dpr=1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&h=800&q=80&cs=tinysrgb" />
  <h2 class="c-graidient__title">Gradient Hover Effect</h2>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution, try this.

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', 'San Francisco', Calibri, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.c-graidient {
  background: #000;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, #000000 0%, #000000 25%, #1e539e 50%, #ff3083 75%, #7800a8 100%);
  /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, #000000 0%, #000000 25%, #1e539e 50%, #ff3083 75%, #7800a8 100%);
  /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #000000 0%, #000000 25%, #1e539e 50%, #ff3083 75%, #7800a8 100%);
  /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  background-size: 400% 400%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: flex;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  max-width: 100vw;
  max-height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .5s all;
}
.c-graidient__img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: #000 url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1466657718950-8f9346c04f8f?dpr=1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&h=800&q=80&cs=tinysrgb) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: .5;
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
}
.c-graidient__title {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: .05em;
}
.c-graidient:hover {
  background-position: 100% 100%;
}
.c-graidient:hover__title {
  text-shadow: 0 0 20px black;
}
```

```html
<a class="c-graidient">
  <div class="c-graidient__img"></div>
  <h2 class="c-graidient__title">Gradient Hover Effect</h2>
</a>
```

Comment: Images are fetched from the API. I cannot put them in css